# JQuery Full Calendar Default View Setting Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have change the default view of a calendar when it intially loads as follow:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek'
});
```

But issue is that the left side timing bar is missing when i am doing this.

Please guys help me .

Thanks,
Rajbir

Answer (score 0):

Use 'agendaWeek', not 'basicWeek'.